# ::after float to right not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Trying to build a table with sort icon next to each column name. (Using bootstrap and font awesome)

Please, refer to the code below

HTML

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Name and Surname</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
th::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0dc";
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Why `float` and `text-align` not working here? Please let me know right CSS code to get it right. I also don't want that `sort` icon to wrapped up like normal text in smaller screens. It should be in fixed right place.

Comment: try to create a working code by including font-awesome, Boostrap and all the relevant CSS ... @editor: please stop making this a snippet! it cannot work without libraries

Comment: What do you want this to look like? I have trouble understanding how two elements in a single row could both have something floating right

Comment: What I want is just to create fixed icon in each right edge of table columns. But problem is that, when I resize my browser that icon is wrapping up and falls below of texts.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3o1ktupx/

Answer (score 0):

i think your mixing up the table tags

```
<table></table> table tag 
<thead></thead> table header
<th></th>       table column 
<tbody></tbody> table body
<tr></tr>       table row 
<td></td>       table cell
<tfoot></tfoot> table footer
```

but to answer your question with the way your current data is structured do it like this just add an empty table cell or column as the case maybe to your table row then use the css below to add what you want to the cell.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>extra table cell</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        tr th:last-child::after {
            font-family: FontAwesome;
            content: " i am what you want";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="table table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Name and Surname</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Name and Surname</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Name and Surname</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```